# if statement in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development, I am currently trying to see if a value entered is equal to a value. Here I am seeing if the user input equals to 5, they are currently set as strings as to is the text field.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_uk_postage);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button home = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnHome);
    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnCalculate);


    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ukPostage.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

    EditText lengthInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLength);
    final String lengths = lengthInput.getText().toString();
    final TextView amount = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtAmount);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if (lengths.equals("5")) {
                amount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

The text goes to visible if i click the button without the if statement there however won't once I write the if statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you think that `final String lengths = lengthInput.getText().toString();` does? better yet, what value does it take when you run it through a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (lengths.equals("5")) {`

`String` is immutable and once you reference it you need to reference it again with your edit text to reflect the latest value.

Instead of the above code you need to reference the `lengths` back with the `lengthInput` value each time you click the calculate button.

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            lengths = lengthInput.getText().toString();
            if (lengths.equals("5")) {
                amount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

IMPORTANT: You need to set the `lengths` as a global variable instead of being a final variable since it can only be initialized once.